# Blank Screen showing up after Image Selected from Gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I am trying to get an image into the ImageView but whenever I click a picture on the Gallery the app shows a blank screen and closes down.
This ImageView is in a fragment

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auction_add, container, false);

```
    auction_add_imageViewButton = v.findViewById(R.id.auction_add_imageView_button);

    auction_add_imageViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageSelectAction(v);
        }
    });


    dateTimeAction(v);


    return v;
}

private void imageSelectAction(View v) {
    auction_add_imageViewButton = v.findViewById(R.id.auction_add_imageView_button);
    auction_add_image = v.findViewById(R.id.auction_add_imageView);

    choosePicture();

}

private void choosePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                auction_add_image.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Inital Declaration

```
public class auction_add extends Fragment {


    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 10;
    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 11;
    ImageButton auction_add_imageViewButton;


    //References to all Auction Add Page EditText
    EditText auction_add_itemNameTxt;
    EditText auction_add_descriptionTxt;
    EditText auction_add_initialPriceTxt;
    EditText auction_add_startTimeTxt;
    EditText auction_add_endTimeTxt;

    //Reference to ImageView
    private ImageView auction_add_image;

    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Would Appreciate the help thanks!

Edit:

Followed is the error on the Run tab of Android Studio

```
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.projectcrest, PID: 5618
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=242868079, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:31 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.projectcrest/com.example.projectcrest.pages.LandingPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5015)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.projectcrest.fragments.auction_add.onActivityResult(auction_add.java:155)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2905)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2885)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:377)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:336)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:624)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5618 SIG: 9
```

Comment: by `shows a blank screen and closes down This ImageView is in a fragment` statement, do you mean that the app closes after selecting the image/photo?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean sorry for the confusion

Comment: When the app is closes this way means something went wrong and an exception was thrown. Could you please be able to look into the Android Logcat and try to post the error message here? The error message would be helpful to provide a correct solution.

Comment: I have added an edit on the post and put the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into the exception it seems that the App is crashing in `#onActivityResult` function at line `auction_add_image.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);` due to NPE (Null Pointer Exception). This expection/crash is caused since the `auction_add_image` object has null value instead of an ImageView.

After taking an close look into your code, I think the issue has occured due to following code:

```
    auction_add_imageViewButton = v.findViewById(R.id.auction_add_imageView_button);

    auction_add_imageViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageSelectAction(v);
        }
    });
```

Note that in `#onClick` function you are passing view `v` on which you are going to perform the #findViewById operation. Here the passed view `v` refers to the `auction_add_imageViewButton` instead of the `v` you have captured above.

I would suggest to modify the code as below (just rename the `v` variable in #onClick function):

```
    auction_add_imageViewButton = v.findViewById(R.id.auction_add_imageView_button);

    auction_add_imageViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View buttonView) {
            imageSelectAction(v);
        }
    });
```

This way the variable name collision could be avoided and the error would be resolved.

Also, in case this does not solve your problem, then please check whether the #findViewById is returning an ImageView instead of null. In case the Id provided to #findViewById is not present on the screen or in the child views of view (on which the #findViewById) is being performed then the #findViewById will return null value.

Also, check whether you have assigned null value to auction_add_image in anywhere your code.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem messed up the references